# prove that this function isn't Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to prove that this function isn't Lipschitz continuous:

$f:[-1,1]\to \Bbb R:x\mapsto x^{2}\sin1/x^{2}$ when $x$ not equal to zero and $0$ if $x=0$.

Now I just can't find the right $x$ and $y$ to prove it.

Take $M$ from $\Bbb  R^+$. Chose then $x$ and $y$ (I can't find them) and it follows that:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|....>M|x-y|$$

but without $x$ and $y$ I can't start the proof at all, can someone just help me with the $x$ and $y$, I would like to finish to prove on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that this function is differentiable at every point. If it is Lipschitz it would follow that its derivative is bounded. But $f'(x)=2x\sin (\frac 1  {x^{2}})-(2/x) \cos (\frac 1  {x^{2}})$. This is unbounded along the sequence $(\frac 1 {\sqrt {2n \pi}})$.

If $x$ and $y$ are sufficiently close to $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2n\pi}}$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| $ would exceed $M|x-y|$.